# Assertion Error when running `SolrTestCaseJ4` tests: Fix your classpath to have tests-framework.jar before lucene-core.jar

Tags: java, solr, lucene

When trying to run simple tests using [Solr's testing framework](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-test-framework/org/apache/solr/SolrTestCaseJ4.html) I get the following Error message:

> java.lang.AssertionError: fix your classpath to have tests-framework.jar before lucene-core.jar
>
> at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed(...)

I'm using the [IntelliJ IDEA IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). How do I fix the classpath to have `tests-framework.jar` before `lucene-core.jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In certain situations, the order of libraries may be important. <..>
>
> For the compilation to succeed, certain libraries (e.g. the ones having to do with the JDK itself and its extensions) must be included in the module bootclasspath. So, such libraries must appear in the list before the JDK.

For more details see [relevant chapter of IntelliJ Web help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/processing-order.html).

Answer (score 2):

Even though @mindas's answer above pointed me to it, it is not in a sense, a direct answer to the question. I faced this exact issue today, and found out that the lucene-core.jar wasn't being pulled itself. I added it to my pom.xml and now I don't get the above mentioned error anymore. Here is what the `<dependencies>` section of my pom.xml now looks like:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-test-framework</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**Note:** Make sure that your lucene-core and solr-test-framework versions match.

Hope this helps someone else landing on this page.